# AngularJS and Google SEO Indexing

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, angular.js

I am not a specialist in SEO, and some time talking to one told me that Google indexes, which is in the **view-source**, I wonder if this is really true?

I am developing an application and took Angle and quite advanced, and I remembered and I wonder if this is true or not.

Why? I ask this.
Because my code in the **view-source** looks like this

```
<article class="uk-article" ng-controller="dataItemHoP">
   <h1 class="uk-article-title"><span>Información</span></h1>
   <h3 class="uk-article-lead"><span>{{nombreHoP}}</span></h3>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Dirección:</span> <br>
      <span>{{direccion}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{ciudad}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{estado}}</span></p>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Teléfonos:</span> <br>
   <span>{{telefono1}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{telefono2}}</span></p>
</article>
```

**While on the console looks like Google**

```
<article class="uk-article ng-scope" ng-controller="dataItemHoP">
   <h1 class="uk-article-title"><span>Información</span></h1>
   <h3 class="uk-article-lead"><span class="ng-binding">Lidodotel Hotel Boutique</span></h3>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Dirección:</span> <br>
   <span class="ng-binding">Centro Comercial Sambil, autopista Antonio Jose de Sucre, sector Las Lomas, edificio Lidotel</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">San Cristóbal</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">Táchira</span></p>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Teléfonos:</span> <br>
   <span class="ng-binding">0276 5103333</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">0276 5103334</span></p>
</article>
```

¿So, Google doesn't will Indexed because into the view-source is watching the {{ expression }} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you see in the console is the site after it is rendered by browser. if the site is properly coded, and all javascripts are loaded fast, you can hope, that the whole site will be indexed. if the time gap for loading of javascripts is more then, say, 4 seconds after onLoad event, it could happens that Googlebot will not wait so long and the site remains not fully indexed.

Comment: Oh thanks, well, my data is provided from the controller in this case, Angular, and the controller is who takes the data from the API Rest. but is an simple App with simple data and images